# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap: null

Tags: java, android, bundle, parcelable

I'm getting this error

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap: null at android.util.ArrayMap.validate(ArrayMap.java:550) at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2486) at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269) at com.example.fragments.QuestionSwipeFragment.handleBundle(SourceFile:197)

not in my current device but it is coming from crashlytics, but I can't regenerate this issue in my own device tried all possible ways but can't get this same error in my device, below is my code, answers would be really appreciated.

```
public class QuestionSwipeFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private View mRootView;
    private int mPosition;
    private List<ResourceModel> mResourceList;
    private QuestionSwipePagerAdapter mQuestionSwipePagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    private int mSelectedChapterId;
    private int mSelectedSectionId;
    private int mSelectedSubSectionId;
    private boolean mSelectedFavourite;

    private boolean mIsFavourite;
    private boolean mIsPagination;

    private int mCurrentPage;
    private int mTotalPage;

    int mResourcePageNo;
    int mMarkId;
    int mDifficulties;

    private int mFragmentType;

    private int mFragType;
    private PaginationParams mPaginationParams = new PaginationParams();

    private static final int RESOURCE_ALL = -1;

    private boolean onDestroy = false;

    private static final String API_TYPE_PAGINATION = "pagination";

    public QuestionSwipeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DialogFragment newInstance(List<ResourceModel> mResourceList, int id, int fragType, boolean isFavourited, boolean isPaginationRequest,
                                             int chapterId, int sectionId,
                                             int resourcePageNo, int markId,
                                             int difficulties, int currentPage,
                                             int totalPage) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        QuestionSwipeFragment fragment = new QuestionSwipeFragment();

        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mResourceList);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST_POSTION, id);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TYPE_FRAGMENT, fragType);

        bundle.putBoolean(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_ISFAVOURITED, isFavourited);
        bundle.putBoolean(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_ISPAGINATIONREQUEST, isPaginationRequest);

        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_CHAPTER_ID, chapterId);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_SECTION_ID, sectionId);

        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCEPAGE_NO, resourcePageNo);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_MARKID, markId);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_DIFFICULTIES, difficulties);


        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_CURRENTPAGE, currentPage);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TOTALPAGE, totalPage);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static DialogFragment newInstance(List<ResourceModel> mResourceList, int position, int fragType,
                                             int selectedChapterId, int selectedSectionId, int selectedSubSectionId, int currentPage, int totalPage) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        QuestionSwipeFragment fragment = new QuestionSwipeFragment();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mResourceList);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST_POSTION, position);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TYPE_FRAGMENT, fragType);

        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_CHAPTER_ID, selectedChapterId);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_SECTION_ID, selectedSectionId);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_SUBSECTION_ID, selectedSubSectionId);

        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_CURRENTPAGE, currentPage);
        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TOTALPAGE, totalPage);

        bundle.putInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_CURRENTFRAGMENT, fragType);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handleBundle(getArguments());
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyMaterialTheme);
    }

//the below method is causing IllegalArgumentException
 private void handleBundle(Bundle bundle) {
          if (bundle != null) {
                if (bundle.containsKey(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST)) {
                    mResourceList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST);
                    mPosition = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCE_LIST_POSTION);
                    mFragType = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TYPE_FRAGMENT);
    
                    mSelectedChapterId = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_CHAPTER_ID);
                    mSelectedSectionId = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_SECTION_ID);
    
                    mSelectedSubSectionId = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_SELECTED_SUBSECTION_ID);
    
                    mIsFavourite = bundle.getBoolean(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_ISFAVOURITED);
                    mIsPagination = bundle.getBoolean(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_ISPAGINATIONREQUEST);
    
                    mCurrentPage = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_CURRENTPAGE);
                    mTotalPage = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_TOTALPAGE);
    
                    mResourcePageNo = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_RESOURCEPAGE_NO);
                    mMarkId = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_MARKID);
                    mDifficulties = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_DIFFICULTIES);
    
                    mFragmentType = bundle.getInt(Constants.QUESTION_SWIPE_CURRENTFRAGMENT);
                }
            }
        }
```

And below is the code where i am starting this fragment from adapter

```
private void setonClickListeners(ResourceQuestionsViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.mContainerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment questionSwipeFragment = QuestionSwipeFragment.newInstance(getExtractResourceInfo(position).getExtractedList(), getExtractResourceInfo(position).getPosition(), Constants.QB_DETAILS_FRAGMENT, isFavourited, isPaginationRequest, chapterId, sectionId, resourcePageNo, markId, difficulties, mCurrentPage, mTotalPage);
                questionSwipeFragment.show(((QuestionBankActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

            }
        });
}

private void setonLongClickListener(SubSectionResourceQuestionsViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.mContainerView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment questionBankFragment = QBSubSectionDetailFragment.newInstance(mResourceList, false, position);
                questionBankFragment.show(((SynopsisActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does it actually give you the line number where that Exception is thrown?

Comment: Ya it says 197 it's the first line of handle bundle method where I m checking bundle null,  

Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate key in ArrayMap: null
       at android.util.ArrayMap.validate(ArrayMap.java:550)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2486)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
       at com.example.fragments.QuestionSwipeFragment.handleBundle(SourceFile:197)

Comment: can you paste your ResourceModel class code here.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm getting this same error.

Comment: Is this issue resolved, facing same in crashlytics?

Comment: Still have any solutions ?

Comment: I added a bounty, here is my crashlytics log:  (wouldn't let me add my log, was too long.  Do I need to add it as an answer, that doesn't seem to be the right place.

Comment: @jonathan3087 the right place would have been a new question. It’s rather unlikely that your problem is related to this question from 2016 when you say that you *didn’t* have this problem *from* 2017 to ??? (some rather recent date?).

Answer (score 0):

When I have this problem it's actually caused by other exceptions

My problem is caused by starting an Activity that is not exported

Solution:

1. Check that your passed argument does have multiple **null** keys
2. Check whether an Activity that is not set to export has been started (for starting other apps)
3. You can set references directly to fragments without passing them through **bundle**

Answer (score 0):

@jonathan3087
Please check below things in your Parcelable class:

- Order of your Parcelable class's field in `writeToParcel()`
- Key name or reusing key or not
- check proguard keep

Comment: I have checked these things previously, but still haven't found the problem.  So, I will go through and check these again.  Thank you for the reply.  It will be a few days before I get back to it, but I will.